# why in linux "ffmpeg" command from nodejs ends after a few seconds

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I am using fluent-ffmpeg to push a file to RTMP server, it is ok but when I run program in Linux OS, ffmpeg stops after a few seconds

```javascript
ffmpeg(flv)
    // .inputOptions(['-readrate', '1']) //is unknown in linux
    .inputOptions('-re') //ok for Windows but is not efficient if linux
    .outputOptions(
        '-c:v', 'libx264',
        '-preset', 'superfast',
        '-fflags', 'nobuffer',
        '-tune', 'zerolatency',
        '-c:a', 'aac',
        '-ar', '44100'
    )
    .autopad()
    .flvmeta()
    .format('flv')
    .on('start', function () {
        console.log("ffmpeg Started!");
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log("ffmpeg Error!", err);
    })
    .on('end', function () {
        started = false;
        console.log("ffmpeg Finished!");
    })
    .output("rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/61a7e51ea1bcbf3d9cbf428d")
    .run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the versions of ffmpeg you're using on Linux and Windows the same? `readrate` might not be available in the version used in Linux.

`-re` is equivalent to `-readrate 1` (See the `readrate` section here https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options.) in versions of ffmpeg where `readrate` is available so there shouldn't be an issue with a lower efficiency.  I'm unsure if using `-re` in an older version of ffmpeg is equivalent to using `-readrate 1` in a newer version of ffmpeg though. If `-re` or `-readrate 1` are used in the same version of ffmpeg.

Edit: I just tested `-re` and `-readrate 1` on the latest development version of ffmpeg `version N-105189-g9a194252c7`. When monitoring the CPU usage in the stream preview I have there is not a noticeable difference between the two.